# java.sql.SQLException: The result set is closed

Tags: java, resultset, sqlexception

When I try to execute my code I get error:

> ERROR [TripDAO] TripDAO: findAllTripsByActivityId()
>                 java.sql.SQLException: The result set is closed.

Methods where I get error looks like:

```
public List<Trip> findAllTripsByActivityId(int id) {
    List<Trip> trips = new ArrayList<Trip>();

    if (obtainConnection()) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement stm = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            stm = con.prepareStatement(findAllTripsByActivityIdQuery
                    .toString());
            logger.info("Wybrano id: " + id);
            stm.setInt(1, id);
            rs = stm.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                trips.add(setInObject(rs));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("TripDAO: findAllTripsByActivityId() " + e);
        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
    }
    return trips;
}

public Trip setInObject(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    Trip trip = new Trip();
    int id = rs.getInt("id");
    trip.setId(id);
    ...
    return trip;
}
```

I have no idea what it could be wrong in this code. Can you help me?

Comment: would you print the whole stack trace? Maybe the underlying stream it's being closed for some reason.

Comment: Somewhere in that `...` you're not posting, you're closing the result set.

Comment: Sorry about my answer, I completely misread the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the entire ResultSet to the `setInObject` method, which is probably what breaks it. Try extracting the values from the result set in your `findAllTripsByActivityId` method.